# How do I get text/html decoder plugins for Python 2.7 (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: python, plugins, internet-radio, html

How do I get text/html decoder plugins for Python 2.7? I have tried all the methods suggested on the forums here.They did not work. In addition to trying Helix-player in the form of Real Player, I also tried Gecko Media Player as Gnome Player, Adobe Flash and all the Ubuntu restricted programs.They did not work either!Python 2.7 keeps looking for these text/html plugins but cannot find them! I need these in order to play some internet radio stations that are supported on an internet radio portal.
Can you help ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the plug-ins for Python 2.7. I'm not sure where you're getting the "for Python 2.7" from, but I would have to guess it's from the program that does the searching for codecs, being written in Python.

Instead, you need codecs for GStreamer.

However, there are no GStreamer plug-ins for handling *text/html*, as it is not a multimedia container format. It's a web page. If you're getting an error about a missing codec for it, the problem is that you're using the wrong URL, or the server is redirecting you to another URL, which is returning HTML, and acting like a successful connection.

You need to use the correct URLS to play these in `Rhythmbox`, `Totem`, or other players.

Comment: are you aware of how to change the urls in Totem so I can play videos from Vimeo in channel tab?

Comment: You would need to write an extension to Totem to enable a Vimeo channel using the Vimeo API, or do something externally which gets the URLs from the Vimeo API and then passes them to Totem.